# How to copy a file for every element in a list, with the file named after that element and replacing a word for the string element in the new file

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a template, copy it and name it as an element of a list, then I need to find an specific word and replace it with the string element. That for every element in the list.

Example

This is What I have

- template file test:
   "XXXX is good"
- list

  1. Mom
  2. Dad
  3. Child

And this is what I need

- create files:

  1. Mom.abc
  2. Dad.abc
  3. Child.abc

-text in created files:

1. "Mom is good"
2. "Dad is good"
3. "Child is good"

The file extension is not txt, but I haven't had any problems with that.

I gave it a try with the code below; the result was just two files (the list had more than two lines) and the 2nd one was empty.

Some help would be much appreciated.

```
template = open ('C:\\Users\\Munoz\\Desktop\\template.abc', 'r')

for element in myList: #For each element in my list
    with open('C:\\Users\\Munoz\\Desktop\\'+element.strip()+'.abc', "w") as newFile: #create a file with the name of the element and abc extension
        for line in template: #for every line in template
            newFile.write(line.replace("Name",element.strip())) #copy the line and replace "Name" with the element name

template.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `template` variable is a file handle, not a string.  Therefore the second iteration of the `for line in template` has nothing left to read because the file pointer is already at the end of the file from the previous time it was run.

You could open the file handle inside the `for` loop for each element, but that would be inefficient.  Or you could reset the file pointer every time using `template.seek(0)`, but again it would be inefficient to read the file every time through the loop.

Better to read the entire file into a list of lines once then iterate through that list of strings.

```
with open('C:/Users/Munoz/Desktop/template.abc', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for element in myList:
    with open('C:/Users/Munoz/Desktop/' + element.strip() + '.abc', "w") as newFile:
        for line in lines:
            newFile.write(line.replace("Name", element.strip()))
```

Comment: that was what I needed